# laravel slug url for different langs

Tags: laravel, seo, slug

I found different libraries to slugify article titles and make them user friendly for seo. However only english text is slugified while arabic for example is not.
Till now I have tried the following:

https://github.com/cocur/slugify

https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable

Any ideas for other libraries that support different langs to slug strings?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for the arabic characters that works with the second library link.
Config file should be replaced with the following one and you're good to go:

https://github.com/morilog/eluquent-sluggable-persian